# ionic tabscontroller make not-first active on startup

Tags: ionic-framework

When you start an ionic application with a tabbar on the bottom, it always starts the App with the first Tab active.

But I have 3 tabs, and I want the Tab in the middle to be the active Tab that starts when I open the App.

Can't find in the docs how to do this. Someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [$ionicTabsDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicTabsDelegate/) for your needs. You can inject it into any controller, or your app's run block. Then you do it similar to the example:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {
  //use 1 to select the second tab (starts with 0)
  $ionicTabsDelegate.select(1);
}
```

if you want to have it when your app starts, put in in your [run block](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

Comment: But that's not when you wanna start the app with another tab then the first. Now it still opens first tab, but goes to the second after a while. That's something I wanna skip.. Just start with middle tab.